# Setting DateTime property to null

Tags: c#

So I have this property and would like to either set the value to what is coming back from the db or to null if it is empty. It is possible to do this with an if-else, but for cleaner code, I would like to use the ternary operator. Could someone point out the mistake I am making. Thanks!!!

```
public DateTime? OptionExpiration {get;set;}
 //actually sets the value to null               
 if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].ToString())){
      OptionExpiration = null;
}else{
      OptionExpiration = DateTime.Parse(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].ToString());
}
```

//so I check the to see if the string is empty or null, then try to set the value but recieve this error: Error 2   Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type '' and 'System.DateTime?'

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].ToString())
? OptionExpiration =  null
| OptionExpiration = DateTime.Parse(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].ToString())
;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like "dapper" instead of all this faffing with data-readers?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using `dr.IsDBNull` instead of trying to access the field first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator wrong.

It should be:

```
OptionExpiration = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"]))
                   ? (DateTime?)null
                   : DateTime.Parse(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].ToString())
                   ;
```

So:

```
assignment = condition ? trueExpression : falseExpression;
```

If the field is a `date` in your database, it might be better to do this:

```
OptionExpiration = Convert.IsDBNull(dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"])
                   ? (DateTime?)null
                   : (DateTime)dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"]
                   ;
```

Comment: and do `(DateTime?)null`, or you will get compiler error

Comment: Or `default(DateTime?)`.

Comment: So it looks like with that the error I get is Error 10 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime' :

Comment: And of course you will get an exception at `xyz.ToString()` if the database value is `NULL`.

Comment: Did you _test_ it on a `null`  value? Because I doubt that `null.ToString` works if `dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"] == null`. {edit} As @ThorstenDittmar already noted.

Comment: If `dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"]` is `null` then there is a problem.  If it is `DBNull.Value` then that's fine as it will return an empty string when `ToString` is called.

Comment: I don't get it - is the field in the database a string or a datetime? If it is a datetime, all of this is obsolete. If it is a string, why isn't it a datetime? :-)

Comment: Indeed. Included a sample if the field is a `date` after all.

Comment: Sorry, the db is pretty old and it is a Date field, it pulls from some other system we have in-house. Also, it works with null values. Thanks again for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an extension method like this:

```
            public static Nullable<DateTime> AsNullableDateTime(this object item, Nullable<DateTime> defaultDateTime = null)
            {
                if (item == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()))
                    return defaultDateTime;

                DateTime result;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(item.ToString(), out result))
                    return defaultDateTime;

                return result;
            }
```

You can pass anything in to this and it will attempt to give you back a date. If it fails for whatever reason (this also checks to make sure the object you send through is not null) you will get a null back; which is fine because you're mapping to a nullable datetime.

To use this you would do something like:

```
OptionExpiration = dr["OPTION_EXPIRATION"].AsNullableDateTime();
```

No mess, easy to understand what is happening, abstracting away the clutter, and highly reusable on other parts of your solution.